# expressionengine publish.php file not working

Tags: expressionengine

I have upgraded the version to 2.5.2 of expressionengine..

in my old version in themes/cp_themes/default/content/publish.php file, have added a custom javascript code and code php too, because whenever I publish or edit any entry from admin side I want to open a window on a button click event.. on that button click event I passed a url to and opening a window which having map.. n that was working excellent..

Now issue is that in my new version 2.5.2 its not working, even not showing that HTML button as well. In Actual publish.php file is not calling.. I have put php exit(); on top of the file.. N I found that, the file publish.php is not calling..

So plz help to for that, I want to apply same changes to my latest version as was in my old version.. So, that in which file have to write that code..??

Can anybody Help me.. Please ASAP..

Thanks,
Jatin